How should I print data to PDF fetched from DB in CodeIgniter 3 view page?
In the CodeIgniter 3 view page I use the following AJAX to fetch some data from DB which consisted of some HTML data:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fetchDataButton').click(function() {
        var activeProfileId = '<?php echo $AKTIF_PROFIL->id; ?>';

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{$user_base_url}}/profil/get_report_content',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { activeProfileId: activeProfileId }, // Pass the active profile ID as data
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                var reportContent_kullanici_profilleri_Full = response.kullanici_profilleri;
                var reportContent_kullanici_profilleri = reportContent_kullanici_profilleri_Full.find(function(item) {
                    return item.id == activeProfileId;                  
            });
            console.log('Data received:', reportContent_kullanici_profilleri);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        });
    });  
});

I want to print this fetched data as PDF by dompdf.
For example the content of fetched data on console is as follows:
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center bg-secondary rounded my-5 py-5">
        <p class="text-white m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod tenetur ex natus at dolorem enim!</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

How should I code for that?
Could anyone provide the required controller /AJAX for that purpose?
